# Может ли слово категории состояния быть подлежащим?

Tags: синтаксис

Разрешите мой давний спор с преподавателем: может ли слово категории состояния быть подлежащим?  Я сказала тогда, что может.
Знаю, что в предложении ***"Жить - хорошо!"*** слово ХОРОШО- сказуемое. А если наоборот? ***"Хорошо - жить!"*** Вот это предложение меня и интересует.

***По завершении дискуссии, в результате которой было доказано, что слово категории состояния не может быть подлежащим,  я нашла информацию***, ***содержащую ответ на вопрос, может ли КС быть сказуемым. Вывод один: давние споры вокруг КС не утихают!***

Трудности возникают при разборе предложений со словами на -о, сочетающими значение оценки и состояния.

***Бабайцева и Максимов*** считают, что такие предложения могут быть как двусоставными, так и односоставными.

I точка зрения
Перед нами односоставное предложение, если инфинитив стоит в **пост**позиции, при этом усиливается значение состояния, особенно при наличии дательного субъекта.

***Скучно нам слушать осенную вьюгу.*** (Н. А. Некрасов)

II точка зрения

При **пре**позиции инфинитива и отсутствии дательного субъекта в словах на -о усиливается значение оценки и по своим лексико-грамматическим свойствам они сближаются с прилагательными. В этом случае перед нами двусоставное предложение с **подлежащим, выраженным инфинитивом:**

***Мечтать — легко и приятно, но думать —трудно.***(К. Д. Ушинский)

***Шанский и Тихонов*** полагают, что и в этом случае слова на -о — это слова категории состояния, они ***являются сказуемым в двусоставном*** предложении.

III точка зрения

***Бабайцева и Чеснокова*** рассматривают данные слова как наречия в функции сказуемого.
Жить хорошо.
Хорошо — сказуемое, выраженное наречием. По школе, данная конструкция рассматривается как прилагательное.
 ***http://www.goldrussian.ru/catalog/sintaksicheskie-osobennosti-kategorii-sostojanija-109.htm***

Comment: Все это и я читала, кажется, в словаре лингвистических терминов у Розенталя. Спасибо за ссылку. Предполагаю, что Бабайцева, говоря о том, что это прилагательное, произвела замену жить хорошо на на жизнь хороша. Я об Этом тоже думала. Однако насколько это правомерно? Она и так намудрила в своем синтаксисе (20 лет по ее учебнику работала, знаю, перед экзаменами детей переучивать приходится.) Тем не менее спасибо большое и за тему, и за комментарии. Вообще форум замечателен тем, что можно посмотреть на привычные явления по-другому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

behemothus опередил меня в ответе, но я с ним согласна.

Слово состояния по определению не может являться подлежащим. Синтаксическая роль категории состояния (главный член безличного предложения) - это её признак, если синтаксическая роль не такая, то это тогда и не категория состояния.

Про предложение еще подумаю.

Что касается терминологии. Подлежащее, сказуемое - терминология двусоставного предложения. Если упрощенно: что обозначает подлежащее? Предмет речи. Сказуемое - что говорится о предмете речи. Поэтому нет подлежащего -  нет сказуемого. В односоставном предложении есть главный член, он по форме может быть похож на подлежащее и сказуемое. (В школьной грамматике так и говорят: подлежащее и сказуемое)

**ДОПОЛНЯЮ:**
Я думаю, что предложения типа хорошо -жить, жить - хорошо, бессмысленно - верить, это бессоюзные сложные предложения, каждая часть которых - односоставная. Хорошо - жить = Если живешь. это хорошо = Если веришь - это не имеет смысла и т.д. Именно поэтому в этих предложениях ставится тире.

Comment: Лара, разберите мне, пожалуйста, предложения типа "Бессмысленно - спорить", "Хорошо - жить!" Или так: "Это бессмысленно - спорить", "это хорошо - жить!". Двусоставное ведь получается... Может, я перестану наконец-то об этом думать! Смотрите: предмет речи - хорошее состояние, о нём говорится, что это состояние называется "жить".

Comment: А вообще, уложить все многообразие предложений в русском языке в  рамки структурного синтаксиса без исключений и вариаций  , на мой взгляд, невозможно.

Comment: ответ дополнила.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Очень признательна!

Comment: А согласны?

Comment: Я очень благодарна и behemothus, и Вам. Соглашусь с тем, что КС не может быть подлежащим. Это главное.  А вот насчёт того, что это БСП, ещё думаю. Вчера нашла информацию о том, что некоторые лингвисты допускали использование категории состояния в качестве сказуемого в двусоставном предложении. Предложение такое: "Я не замужем". Как Вам?

Comment: "Не замужем" - это сказуемое? Ведь краткие прилагательные могут быть сказуемым, не так ли? Ср. с "Я незамужняя".

Comment: Еще раз: именно синтаксическая функция (главный член безличного предложения) позволяет назвать слово состояния таковым. Если это сказуемое в двусоставном предложении - это не категория состояния. Кстати, в толковых словарях (Ушаков. Ожегов) обозначена часть речи - наречие.

Answer (score 2):

Пример можно?

Вообще подобные вопросы не имеют объективного решения. Всё зависит от построения формализованной грамматики языка. Соответвенно и взгляды на проблему могут меняться. 
Да еще школьная грамматика запросто может расходиться с академической.

Сейчас, вроде, такие слова признаются в лучшем случае "главными членами", а термин "подлежащее" зарезервирован за двусоставными (подлежащее+сказуемое) предложеними.
Может, меня и поправят.

> > > А если наоборот? "Хорошо - жить!" Вот это предложение меня и интересует.

Вообще-то я и в первом случае сомневаюсь, что "хорошо" - сказуемое. Если хорошо - сказуемое, то "жить" подлежащее. А по каноническим предствалениям категория состояния может быть сказуемым только в предложениях без подлежащего.
Нет, скорее всего это знаменательная часть составного именного сказуемого с опущенной связкой "есть". В такой роли категория состояния вполне нормальна.

Но уж во втором - точно не подлежащее. Я думаю, что грамматически это тоже самое предложение с инверсией порядка членов. Сравните: "жить было хорошо" и "хорошо было жить".  Разве грамматика поменялась?

Впрочем, я рассуждаю, а не докладываю. Готов услышать контраргументы.

Answer (score 0):

Тире не ставится, если
 1. Подлежащее выражено инфинитивом, сказуемое – категорией наречия, на -о (Курить вредно. Струсить ужасно.)

1. Тире ставится между подлежащим, выраженным инфинитивом, и сказуемым, выраженным наречием на -о, при наличии паузы между главными членами (Ужасно – струсить. Вредно - курить).

Ужасно струсить. Вредно курить- без интонации.

Comment: подлежащее и сказуемое поменялись местами во втором случае.

Comment: Нет, ошиблась. Здесь вредно - не категория состояния, а наречие. Курить (каково?)вредно. 

Вредно курить. Здесь _Курить_ - тоже подлежащее. Но стоит не  в начале предложения. Если сказуемое перед подлежащим стоит, то запятую не ставим. Если в первом случае можно при соответствующей интонации поставить тире, то во втором - нет, с логическим ударением на _вредно_. Если же написать с тире, то получим: Вредно - курить. это уже безличное предложение. и _вредно_ здесь - категория состояния, в функции сказуемого, а _курить_ - дополнение.

Comment: Подойти к брату (-) страшно – двусоставное предложение. Подойти - подлежащее. Страшно - сказуемое. Тире ставится или нет в зависимости от интонации.
Страшно подойти к брату.- односоставное безличное предложение. Страшно - категория состояния, как член предложения - сказуемое. подойти к брату - дополнение.

Comment: Мечтать — легко и приятно, но думать — трудно.(К. Д. Ушинский)

Мечтать - подлежащее. Легко и приятно - именная часть составного сказуемого, выраженная наречиями.

Comment: Скучно нам слушать осеннюю вьюгу. (Н. А. Некрасов)

Скучно - категория состояния, или предикатив, или безлично-предикативное слово. Как член этого безличного предложения - сказуемое.

Comment: Жить хорошо. Хорошо — сказуемое, выраженное кратким прилагательным.

 Мне хорошо. хорошо - предикатив, или категория состояния. было хорошо - сказуемое безличного предложения.

Он сделал работу хорошо. хорошо - наречие (как?)

Утро было хорошо. хорошо - краткое прилагательное, в функции именной части составного именного сказуемого. Предложение двусоставное.